# Mechanism of oxidation by dichlorotriazenetrione

Tags: redox

How does dichlorotriazenetrione supply chlorine to a swimming pool and how does it oxidize organic material?

Comment: I am only trying to help when I say that a good rule of thumb when asking questions is to make sure it is not a mere one sentence in length. Otherwise, it shows lack of research. Anyone trying to answer has no idea where you are coming from, why you want to know, and what background of knowledge you already have to make the progression to "learnt" much more efficient. [Google](dichloro-s-triazinetrione water purification)

Answer (score 2):

Dichlorotriazenetrione, also known as dichloroisocyanuric acid, is slowly hydrolyzed in water to isocyanuric acid and hypochlorous acid, which serves as the oxidation agent. The N-Cl bond is easily hydrolyzed because of its relative weakness, which is also reflected in the stability of nitrogen halides. The slow hydrolysis releases a low but constant amount of oxidizers. $\ce{HOCl}$ itself oxidizes organic compounds, being reduced to $\ce{HCl}$ in the process.

[image]

In aqueous solution, $\ce{HOCl}$ is in equilibrium with its anhydride $\ce{Cl2O}$ and elemental chlorine, which also serve as oxidizers. Furthermore, it slowly decomposes to $\ce{HCl}$ and oxygen, so that a mixture of different oxidation agents is present in its solution.

$$\ce{HCl + HOCl \rightleftharpoons Cl2 + H2O}$$

$$\ce{2HOCl \rightleftharpoons Cl2O + H2O}$$

$$\ce{2HOCl \rightarrow 2HCl + O2}$$